# How can I use the solve() function inside of itself?

Tags: problem-solving, calculator

I'm trying to use the `solve` function recursively on my TI-89 calculator. Minimal example to demonstrate the concept:

```
solve( y + solve(x=2, x) = 3)
```

Which should give `y=1`. Instead, it gives the rather unhelpful `(y+x=y+2)=1`. I think this is happening because `solve` returns an equality rather than a number, and my example evaluates as

```
solve( y + (x=2) = 3)
```

Instead of the intended

```
solve( y + 2 = 3)
```

How can I work around this? Is there a function that returns the value `2` from the expression `x=2`? Or another way I can force `solve` to do what I want? I've browsed the catalog but none of the built-in functions  seem to do what I want.

**Edit:**

I want to do this in a single expression, not using an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable as a solution to the $solve()$ function, and then plug it in another $solve()$ equation - or basically, put the solution to the $solve()$ function into a variable.

As an example, the $solve(x=2, x)$ that you've mentioned can be defined by the variable $z$ using the STO→ button on your calculator (In this case, type in $solve(x=2,x)$, then press STO → $z$, so the equation is stored in the variable,  and then put in $solve(y+z=3)$, and solve for any variable you want.

Comment: Of course, but I'm trying to accomplish this in a single expression. I'll edit the question.